# Regular expression to allow two non-consecutive dots before "@" in the email validation

Tags: javascript

I have used the below regular expression to validate the email ids, can someone please correct this regex to allow the email ids which contain two non-consecutive dots like "**test.a.@gmail.com**" before "@".

regex:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|^(?!.*\.{2})[a-z0-9]|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
```

Comment: “When regex is your hammer everything looks like a thumb.” Have you considered using something other than a regex to validate your email addresses?

Comment: FYI, even if regex is a really nice tool, it's documented that a single regex can't validate all valid emails

Comment: Thanks, @DaveNewton, Thanks @Apolo for the reply. I found this one and it is working fine for this scenario.

  var validRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;